# Get part numbers for all parts supplied by more than one supplier

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

Im confused with the above **query**, what it is trying to say and what will be the **Oracle Query** for that.

I have the following table:

```
 Supp(S_No, S_Name, Status, City)

 Supp2(S_No, P_No, Quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query to select Part Number (P_No) where Supplier (S_No) is higher than one.

```
SELECT Supp2.P_No 
FROM Supp2 
GROUP BY Supp2.P_No 
HAVING COUNT(SP.S_No) > 1;
```